# Magento site to site stock availability

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I have two independently run Magento sites (different owners), "Site One" **1.7x** and "Site Two" **1.8x**.

The *inventory*, *pricing*, *attributes*, *images* etc are all identical.

However site one updates all stock and either enables or disables the sku if its in stock or not.

What is the best way to automatically update the stock status from site one to site two? Does anyone know of any extensions or can you do it via Magento? I have had a good search and haven't found anything that suits what hopefully is easy enough to do.

Comment: do you actually want to sync the inventory ? are those two sites shares same warehouse or inventory?

Comment: Both sites physically share the same inventory. The inventory is already the same on both sites.  I wish to sync the inventory "status" which has the option of being enabled or disabled.

Comment: Did you tried with setting up a cron .. i have no idea how to accomplish sync in two different magento instances, but magento have a multisite feature, which may not be ur case :-(